Representation/factorising of symplectic groups elements
According to Hall Chap. 3 Corollary 3.47: for a connected matrix Lie group $G$, every element $A\in G$ can be written in the form $A=e^{X_1}e^{X_2}...e^{X_k}$
for some $X_i\in g$, where $g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$.
Take the case where the group $G$ are canonical linear symplectic transformations whose Lie algebra are the Hamiltonian vector fields $\dot{x}=J\nabla H = JMx$ with quadratic Hamiltonian $H=x^TMx$. That is $J=-J^T$ is the canonical symplectic matrix and $M=M^T$ is a symmetric matrix.
Question:
Let $W_i=w_iw_i^T$ be symmetric rank-1 matrices, for $w_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it possible to write
$$e^{hJM}=e^{hJW_1}e^{hJW_2}...e^{hJW_k}$$
for some $k$?
Note that the above corollary doesn't necessarily apply as $JW_i$ are in a subset of $g=\{JM\,|\,M=M^T\text{and }J \text{ symplectic}\}$.
I just need to show that it is possible. Finding the minimum $k$ such that this representation holds is a bonus. If not, showing that you can increase $k$ and get an arbitrarily accurate expression would be very useful.
I have numerical evidence suggesting that this is true for many matrices $M$, i.e., I have optimised $\|e^{hJM}-e^{hJW_1}e^{hJW_2}...e^{hJW_k}\|$ over the $W_i$s for certain $k$ and given $M$ and we find a solution to machine precision.
Potentially helpful facts:

The matrix $JW_i$ is nilpotent, meaning $(JW_i)^2=0$ .
This implies $e^{hJW_i}=I+hJW_i$.
The right hand side can be expanded into it's BCH series.


There is an ambiguity in the question regarding the presence of the parameter $h$: are the parameter $k$ and the matrices $W_1, \dots, W_k$ from the decomposition supposed to be dependent or independent on $h$? A decomposition exists in the dependent case, but not necessarily in the independent one.

$h$-dependent case: In this case, absorbing $h$ into $M$ and the $W_j$s, it suffices to prove this decomposition for $h=1$. Then the general principles underlying Hall's Corollary 3.47 apply here too.
The gist of the existence of a decomposition of the type $A = e^{X_1}e^{X_2} \dots e^{X_k}$ (where $k$ is allowed to depend on $A$) for every $A$ in the connected Lie group $G$ is that such a decomposition exists over some (connected) neighborhood of the identity of the Lie group. Indeed, assume that such a decomposition holds over some open set $Id \in U \subset G$. Since $G$ is a connected $G$-homogeneous space, one can (recursively) cover $G$ by left-translates of $U_i := g_i \circ U$, where each $g_i$ belongs to a previously defined $U_j$ (the recursion being initiate with $U_0 = U$). Since every $g \in U = U_0$ admits a decomposition as above, it follows recursively that every $g \in U_i$ does too, hence every $g \in G$.
Corollary 3.47 follows from this general principle: since the allowable matrices $X_j$s are taken from the whole Lie algebra, and since the exponential map is a local diffeomorphism, we do have the existence of such a neighborhood $U$.
So your question boils down to proving that the subset $Y$ of the Lie algebra (of symmetric matrices*) consisting of (symmetric) rank-1 matrices has the property that a neighborhood $U$ as above exists. Since the exponentiation is a local diffeomorphism and since $Y$ is a conic subset of the Lie algebra (i.e. $Y$ is invariant under multiplication by scalars), it suffices to prove that $Y$ spans the Lie algebra. For this, first note that any diagonal matrix $D = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n W'_i$ where $W'_i = \lambda_i  e_i e_i^T$ is a symmetric rank-1 matrix. Then note that, by the spectral theorem, every symmetric $M$ is of the form
$$Q^{-1} D Q = \sum_{i=1}^n (Q^{-1}W'_i Q) =: \sum_{i=1}^n W_i$$
where $Q$ is orthogonal, hence $M$ is a sum of symmetric rank-1 matrices. (Remark: Hence, for every matrix $e^M$ in $U$, the decomposition $e^M = \prod_{j=1}^k e^{W_j}$ can be accomplished with $k = n$.)
*I discuss here the case of exponentiation of symmetric matrices, but multiplying symmetric matrices by $J$, a similar conclusion holds for exponentiation of Hamiltonian matrices.

$h$-independent case: For symmetric $M$, there does not always exist a decomposition of the form
$$ e^{hJM} = e^{hJW_1} \dots e^{hJW_k}$$
holding for every $h$, where the parameter $k$ and the rank-1 symmetric matrices $W_j$s are $h$-independent.
Indeed, if $M$ does admit such a decomposition, then each Hamiltonian matrix $H_i := JW_i$ satisfies $H_i^2 = 0$ (for $W_i = w_i w_i^T$ for some (column) vector $w_i$, hence $H_i^2 = (Jw_i)[w_i^T (Jw_i)]w_i^T$ and $w_i^T (Jw_i) = 0$ since $J$ is orthogonal). From that, it follows that $e^{hH_i} = 1 + h H_i$, and so $e^{hJM}$ is a (matrix-valued) polynomial in $h$ (of degree $k$). In other words, for all $L > k$, we have $\lim_{h \to \pm \infty} |h|^{-L} e^{hJM} = 0$.
However, it is easy to find examples of Hamiltonian matrices $H$ ($=JM$) for which $e^{hH}$ is not polynomial in $h$. For instance, in dimension $2$, take $H = \mathrm{diag}(1, -1)$, so that $e^{hH} = \mathrm{diag}(e^h, e^{-h})$ (which admits no $L$ large enough to have $\lim_{h \to \pm \infty} |h|^{-L} e^{hH} = 0$).
Remark: Exponentiation of symmetric matrices can be achieved in a $h$-independent matter. Indeed, we showed above that every symmetric matrix $M$ is of the form $\sum_{i=1} W_i$ where the $W_i$ are symmetric rank-1 matrices (in fact, $W_i = \lambda_i Q^{-1} e_i e_i^T Q$). So we have $W_i W_j = \lambda_i \lambda_j \delta_{ij}$ (the Kronecker delta), which implies that the $W_i$s pairwise commute. Hence, if the problem were to exponentiate symmetric matrices, we would have $e^{hM} = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{h W_i}$ for all $h$. In comparison, in the Hamiltonian case, the corresponding Hamiltonian matrices $JW_i$ do not necessarily commute.

Perfect! Thanks heaps, this really helps my intuition on this lemma. Yes the situation is that $w_i$ can depend on $h$ :)
Is it therefore correct to say, for the following to exist: $e^{X_0}=e^{Y_1}...e^{Y_k}$ for $Y_i\in \mathfrak{h}$, a subset of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, one would have to prove that there exists a neighbourhood around the identity $U$ such that $U\subset\mathfrak{h}$ spans the algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Then you can apply the above lemma?

@Ben94 I don't really know what are the quantifiers in your new question (for instance, is $X_0 \in \mathfrak{g}$ arbitrary?), so to that extent I cannot fully answer you. In my answer, one can replace the subset $Y$ by its intersection $Y \cap V$ with an open subset $V$ of $0$ in $\mathfrak{g}$. However, one needs $Y$ (or $Y \cap V$) to be conical, otherwise $Y \cap V$ would only generate a sublattice of $\mathfrak{g}$ and hence taking exponentiation would only lead to a 'discrete' subgroup.

Forgive the ambiguity... new terminology for me. So from what i understood: $V$ is a subset of $\mathfrak{g}$ containing 0. You can instead take $Y\cap V$ also containing 0. Then $Y\cap V$ must be invariant under scalar multiplication and then you can show that it spans $\mathfrak{g}$. Then you can apply the corollary? I haven't heard of "conical"... is this so we can take sums of elements in Y to span $\mathfrak{g}$? Lastly, how do you get $n=k$? I get that in the algebra, you only need $n$ sums, but I can't fully see how this is still the case when mapping it to the group? Cheers

@Ben94 '$Y$ is conical' means that for all $y \in Y$ and all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $ty \in Y$, i.e., $Y$ is invariant under dilations. What matters here in this conical condition is really that it allows for arbitrarily small elements (so that, by exponentiation, one stands a chance to cover a whole neighborhood of the identity $e \in G$). Hence it suffices to take $Y \cap V$ where $V$ is a ball around $0 \in \mathfrak{g}$. If $Y \cap V$ spans $\mathfrak{g}$, with basis $y_1, \dots, y_n$ say, then the map $\sum_i t_i y_i \mapsto \prod_i e^{t_iy_i}$ is a local diffeomorphism near $0$.

Thanks. I see how $k\le n$ for the symmetric case: $e^{M}=\prod_{i=1}^n e^{W_i}$ as $W_i$ commute. But I still can't see how we can get $k\le n$ for the Hamiltonian case i.e., $e^{JM}$ as $JW_i$ don't commute. I believe you are correct (I have confirmed it numerically for a few matrices), but I am missing something in my understanding.

@Ben94 You can parametrize $\mathfrak{g}$ via $n$ parameters, say $(t_1, \dots, t_n) \mapsto \sum_i t_i y_i$. Then consider the map $E := \mathfrak{g} \to G$ defined by $\sum_i t_i y_i \mapsto \prod_i e^{t_i y_i}$. Morally using the Leibniz rule, you can prove that the differential
$$ T_0 E : T_0 \mathfrak{g} \cong \mathfrak{g} \to T_1 G =: \mathfrak{g}$$
is the identity, thus bijective. Hence $E$ is a diffeomorphism from a neighborhood of $0 \in \mathfrak{g}$ onto a neighborhood of $1 \in G$. Commutativity of the $e^{t_i y_i}$s is irrelevant here.

I think I have been lacking a deep enough understanding of what the consequences of $E$ being a diffeomorphism are. Is this reasoning correct: as there exists a diffeomorphism between $\mathfrak{g}$ to $G$, then they are isomorphic (locally), meaning every $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ there is a unique element $E(X)\inG$. As $X$ can be parameterised with $n$ parameters, therefore so can $E(X)$?

So can we summarise this as: due to Lemma 3.47 and the reasoning you gave in your answer there exists a map from $X=\sum_i t_iy_i$ to some $e^{t_ky_1}...e^{t_ky_k}$. And because this map is a diffeomorphism, every element $E(X)\in G$ has a unique element in $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ and therefore you must be able to write it in $n$ factors (e.g., using my previous comment).

@Ben94 I'll rephrase. You have the exponential map $e : \mathfrak{g} \to G$ which, in general, is not globally a diffeomorphism, but it is locally (near $0 \in \mathfrak{g}$ to near $1 \in G$).  Pick a basis ${y_i}$ for $\mathfrak{g}$; every $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ can be uniquely written as $X = \sum_i t_i y_i$. Using this basis, you can define a smooth map $E : \mathfrak{g} \to G$ by $E(\sum_i t_i y_i) = \prod_i e^{t_i y_i}$. Direct computations show that $T_0 E$ is invertible. By the inverse function theorem, $E$ is a local diffeomorphism (around $0 \in mathfrak{g}$ to around $1 \in G$).
